# Efficient way to upload huge data into database from CSV file?

Tags: csv, grails, processing-efficiency

I am working on .csv file in which there are 5,000 `Contacts` in it. What I need is to insert all the contacts into single `Group`. But while doing this it taking so much time almost 30 minutes to insert data into database.

So how can I increase the efficiency of insertion time so that it will done in acceptable time.

Here is code snippet:

```
 def groovyFile = new File(webDirectory, fileName)
 groovyFile.eachLine {
     def variables = it.split(',')
     contactInstance = new Contact(name: '', number: variables.getAt(0))
    ...
    group.addToContacts(contactInstance)
 }
group.save(flush: true)
```

The problem occurs because it render 5K time for each contact in the .csv file?

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: Well, flushing every save is definately going to slow things down. Is this something that must be done within the Grails app, meaning it's part of the app's functionality, or can it be done (one time) outside of the app using the database's restoration tools?

Comment: You can try to use multi threading, cut your csv file for few groups(for example 1000 for each thread) and save it. It maybe will help you. But i'm not sure.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa ! Thank you for the reply. Can I write an sql stored procedure for this. The question here is 'how', in which we import `.csv` file and all the process done in it.

Comment: I can think of two approaches. The fastest way would be to prepare a file which the database tools can load. For example, in postgresql the tool is pg_restore. But this approach is really for admins. It has nothing to do with Grails. If loading the csv is part of what the app must be able to do, then optimizing your code may be the better way. Which of these is the best fit?

Answer (score 1):

See this great blog post on the subject

http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql

In short, you should not user flush: true for each save, but instead should flush the session every couple hundred inserts like so:

```
def cleanUpGorm() {
    def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
    session.flush()
    session.clear()
    propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
}
```

Comment: Raz Abramov! well sorry I havn't mention before that I am saving & flushing `Group` object outside `each loop` and still it takes same time. I tried which you have mentioned but I'm fail in it maybe I loss somewhere but thanks for the response :)

Comment: Happy to help, contact me if you need assistance